# System call return value in C

Tags: c, linux

I am using system function in C code to invoke cp command.
I want to know whether it got executed successfully or not?

Answer (score 7):

Use [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function. It returns the status of command executed. If this is 0, then it would seem this is successfull.

Answer (score 4):

Should be enought to check the return value of `system` call.

From `man system` on Mac:

> The system() function returns the exit
>   status of the shell as returned by
>   waitpid(2), or -1 if an error occurred
>        when invoking fork(2) or waitpid(2).  A return value of 127
>   means the execution of the shell
>   failed.